Identify movie about failed author who falls in with child gang, finds his mojo
I rented this from Blockbuster, so you know how long ago this happened. 
Here are the fragments I can remember: 

The title was something along the lines of "12 seconds of fame" or "15 minutes of fame" or a play on something along those lines. 
Believe movie was made/distributed in the 90's. Definitely not 80's or 2000's. 
The main character is a journalist or professional writer of some sort, leading a normal boring life. He has the "ability" to turn street lamps on and off seemingly at will (this is apparently a thing called "Street Light Interference" phenomenon). He attempts to go for "the big promotion" and gets into a fight with his boss/editor – the boss tells him his writing lacks texture because he has no life experiences. 
The man's life rapidly falls apart and he becomes homeless. During his downward spiral, he realizes that he has lost his "Streetlight Interference" ability; there is a scene of him desperately trying to make a streetlight turn on to no avail.
He then falls in with a street gang made up of children, who are thieves. They live in the sewer. Their leader is an adult living in the sewer with them who gives them cigarettes and candy to ensure their loyalty. 
The man gets into many hijinks with kids and is still attempting to finish his Opus Magnum throughout all these adventures. At some point (end of the 2nd act?) he finishes and submits it to his former editor/boss. 
He falls in love with some random female hobo.
His editor tracks him down in an alley and tells him the manuscript is the greatest piece of literature he's ever read, and that he has a plane ticket and a million dollar advance (or whatever actual amount) check waiting for him. He can leave the gutter now.
His editor is standing on one end of the alley backlit by a limo, the author's hobo girlfriend is standing at the other; he has to make his choice. 
The final shot of the movie is the author reclining in the limo as it cruises down the freeway. After the closeup shot in the car, we see a far off shot of the limo as it drives away; as it passes each streetlight the streetlight turns on.

So a few things: I obviously remember a lot of this movie, but with a couple caveats:
*I may be remembering two or more separate movies and combining them.
*Any of these points could be a pure fabrication; I simply don't remember.
You'd think with this much detail I'd have been able to find it, but I've spent eons googling and on Reddit with no luck. I suspect it was extremely indie, since the store I went to obviously had some true clerks-level movie geeks working it.
Thanks for any help and sorry for the long post!
-S

I've been looking for this movie for forever, too!
...And I found it!
It's called The Last Minute.
Additional information:
The Last Minute is a 2001 UK film which very likely, was available from Blockbuster video, a now-defunct video chain. The title does not contain wordplay related to the common phrase “15 minutes of fame”, though it does contain the word “minute”. The film was released in 2001, though was more than likely developed/produced in the late-90s.
The main character is an up-and-coming star in the film world. He has the ability to turn street lamps on at will. The man’s life rapidly falls apart! He gets into hijinks! He falls in love! He ends up leaving the gutter!
The final shot of the movie is the main character driving away in a car… as the streetlights turn on as he passes! His powers have been restored! And perhaps most importantly... it is the film the question-asker has been trying to find!
More information available on wikipeida
